# Spring boot application as a shipable standalone jar

Tags: spring-boot, jar

So I created a spring boot application. And I simply like to run it as a program from a Main class. No need for web controller access.

It runs great in my Intellij.

But how do I ship it as a jar?

Comment: What isn't clear about the [Creating an Executable Jar](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#getting-started-first-application-executable-jar) section in the reference guide? Basically add the spring boot plugin, do `mvn package` and you have an executable jar.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your project structure. If you use maven just run "maven install" and find your jar in your local repository. 
When you have it, run "java -jar your.jar"